# Download OSM Tiles, connection reset by peer

Tags: java, android, osmdroid, download

I've been trying to download OSM Tiles for offline usage based on a fixed area, and the codes have been working fine for awhile.

However, I've been facing this error recently:

```
ERROR(8936): recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

I'm just wondering if this is due to OSM's server problems, or is it some type of inefficient coding conventions that is causing this problem?

These are my codes for downloading:

```
for (int y = placeTopLeft.getYTile(); y <= placeBottomLeft.getYTile(); y++){
    for(int x = placeTopLeft.getXTile(); x <= placeBottomRight.getXTile(); x++){
        try {
            String urlStr = "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/"+ v +"/"+x+"/"+y+".png";
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            File newFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
                                + "/test/"+ tID+ "/"+v+"/"+x);

            newFileDir.mkdirs();
            File newFile = new File(newFileDir, y+".png");
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read()) != -1) {
                output.write(read);
                output.flush();
            }
            urlConnection.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            mNotificationHelper.cancelled();
            Log.e("URL::: ERROR", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        loopCount++;
        publishProgress( (int) ((loopCount/totalLoopCount) * 100 ) );
    }
}
```

Let me know if I'm missing any other details to order to showcase this error clearer, thanks!

Comment: If you are familiar with MOBAC, you could try downloading the tiles from the same area using that. It would at least tell you if there is a problem at the server end.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what MOBAC is?

Comment: Mobile Atlas Creator http://mobac.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Ah that solution wouldn't work for my as my downloads are dynamic, it's based on user parameters to decide which maptiles will be downloaded which MOBAC doesn't provide as it gives fixed maps.

Comment: As indicated by Greenapps most tile providers do not like you doing this, go and read the apropriate terms of use.  Unless you are going to provide your own tile server it's not advisable.

Comment: But there are many other apps out there that provide map downloads for specific areas as well...? They don't seem to have this problem even when the downloads are for areas much bigger than mine for different zoom levels...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the tiles you got before? Were they real mapnik tiles? When I use a.tile.openstreetmap.org, b.tile.openstreetmap.org or c.tile.openstreetmap.org then very soon the tiles only display the Open Street Map logo and the message 'This application is blocked for overusing .... our servers".

Comment: I believe they are real mapnik tiles. How do I tell if they are not...?